# Error when installing npm in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

I have installed node.js and when trying to install npm I get this error.

> ```
> (base) yovel@the-beastpad:~$ sudo apt install npm
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> (base) yovel@the-beastpad:~$
> ```

Comment: Doesn't `npm` come with Node? At least that's what [npm says](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev node-gyp libssl1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Answer (score -1):

You Must  try this

first update apt with

```
sudo apt update
```

then

```
sudo apt install npm
```

Comment: I have tried this. It doesn't work. the error is still the same.